# Using StartTransaction Method of TOrasession

Tags: delphi, commit, delphi-2010, rollback

While I am using ToraQuery for updating some information in my project.
It is distributed system. Many users can update information simultaneously.

What I need to know is if I am updating this from one computer, will another user be queued or another user is able to update or insert new data?

Shall i check Intransaction before starting the transaction?

My code:

```pascal
Try
  gs_sessionname.db.StartTransaction;
  For I:=0 To CLBTestName.Items.Count-1 Do
  Begin
    If CLBTestName.Checked[I]=True Then
    Begin
      pi_PatientTestId:=ArrayPatientTestID[I];          
      pi_PrimaryId:=GetNewLongIntKeyValue('TestCancelValidationLog','TCValidationId');
      with Query_Void do
      Begin
         Close;
         session:=gs_sessionname;
         sql.Clear;
         sql.add(' Insert Into TestCancelValidationLog(TCValidationId,PatientId,');
         sql.add(' PatientTestId,TestCode,TestName,ModifyDate,ModifyTime');
         IF CB_CancelTest.Checked=False Then
         sql.add(' ,MakeValidBy')
         Else
         sql.add(' ,MakeInvalidBy');
         sql.add(' ) Values ('+IntToStr(pi_PrimaryId)+','+LabelPatientId.Caption);
         sql.add(' ,'+IntToStr(pi_PatientTestId)+','+#39+LabelTestCode.Caption+#39);
         sql.add(' ,'+#39+StringReplace(LabelTestName.Caption,'''','''''',[rfReplaceAll])+#39);
         sql.add(' ,'+#39+ServerDate.TodaysDate+#39+','+#39+ServerDate.TodaysTime+#39);
         sql.add(' ,'+IntToStr(gi_UserId)+')');
         ExecSQL;

         { Patient Test }
         Close;
        session:=gs_sessionname;
         sql.Clear;
         sql.add(' Update PatientTest Set');
         IF CB_CancelTest.Checked=False Then
         Begin
           sql.add(' WorkingStatus=''REG''');
           sql.add(' ,SampleID=0');
         End
         Else
         sql.add(' WorkingStatus=''FE''');
         sql.add(' where PatientId='+LabelPatientId.Caption);
         sql.add(' and PatientTestId='+IntToStr(pi_PatientTestId));
         ExecSQL;

         { Update Temp Table }
         Close;
         DatabaseName:=gs_TempPath;
         sql.Clear;
         sql.add(' Update PathologyMain.db Set');
         IF CB_CancelTest.Checked=False Then
         sql.add(' WorkingStatus=''REG''')
         Else
         sql.add(' WorkingStatus=''FE''');
         sql.add(' where PatientTestId='+IntToStr(pi_PatientTestId));
         ExecSQL;

      End;
    End;
  End;
  gs_sessionname.db.Commit;
  Frm_Message.ShowModal;

Except
  gs_sessionname.db.RollBack;
  MessageDlg(' Failure To Valid Test Cancel.',mtWarning,[mbok],0);
  Exit;
End;



  Function GetNewLongIntKeyValue(Const      RealTableName,KeyFieldName:String):LongInt;
 begin
  With Query_GetNextNo do
   begin
      close;
      DatabaseName:=gs_DatabaseName;
      sql.Clear;
      sql.add('Select max('+KeyFieldName+') AS nMax from '+RealTableName);
      open;
      result:=fieldByName('nMax').AsInteger+1;
      close;
 end;
```

end;

Comment: You've got a transaction there. Why do you suspect that the DB won't respect that transaction? Is there a problem with the DB?

Comment: yes . with this code there is a problem. when i run this program at different machines, sometimes at some point same TCValidationId is generated from different users for different patients. it is though rare case, but it is coming.

Comment: Please don't ask the question in the comments. Please edit the question to ask what you want to ask. Now, how are your generating the ID? What is `GetNewLongIntKeyValue`? Are you using a DB generator?

Comment: its a Function to generatenew id. i have edited above code and added this function too. What must i do to avoid multiple same ids for different patients

Comment: Use a DB generator. Why did you not heed my advice, and edit the information that you presented in the comments in to the question? Only in the comments can anyone glean that your problem is non unique IDs.

Comment: [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/html/A96524_01/c21cnsis.htm) uses `READ COMMITTED` as default transaction level. This allows non-repeatable reads. I'm not an oracle expert, but my suggestion is to use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.

Comment: @ventiseis That sounds like the wrong solution. This problem is what generators were invented for.

Comment: @shishirghimire Please consider using a generator (Oracle calls it `SEQUENCE`) like D. Heffernan proposed. You can improve `INSERT` performance too because you won't have to calculate the next id yourself and wait for another sql query. And setting a higher transaction level may degrade application performance or - in worst case - lead to a deadlock because of transaction isolation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't post it as answer because it was just an idea how the desired result could be achieved. I didn't say it's a good and foolproof solution.

Comment: Thanks, these information you provided yield me muck, Thanks both of you. Used DB generator and used serializable in one transaction. it helped me .